# How to rank tuple value in nested dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, tuples, ranking

I am trying to make a function that accepts a database and a year and it calculates the ranking of the names based on their count and then updates the database.

```
database = {('Spot','DOG'): {2013: (612, 1), 2014: (598, 3)},
            ('Princess','CAT'): {2013: (713, 2)},
            ('Smokey', 'CAT'): {2013: (523, 1), 2014: (514, 1)},
            ('Fido', 'DOG'): {2013: (558, 2), 2014: (655, 1)},
            ('Sparky','DOG'): {2104: (572, 2)}}
```

I have to rank the cats and dogs separately with the most popular name being rank 1, so descending order.

I'm only allowed to use basic expressions and statements, `len, range, enumerate, int, get, items, keys, values, pop, copy, popitem, update, append, insert, extend,min, max, index, split, join, replace, sorted, sort, reversed, reverse, sets` and basic expressions and statements and I can write my own functions and use them.

I can't import modules or use lambda or any thing besides whats on the allowed list. That is why I am stuck. This is my first programming class. I have no idea how to sort the tuple. I know how to sort a nested dictionary, there was a great post on here for that, but I am stuck at this tuple. Could you please help.

```
def rank_names_for_one_year(db, year):
    list = []
    list_2 = []
    for k in db:
        if 'MALE' in k:
            for key in db[k]:
                if year == key:
                    for n in db[k][year]:
                        list.append(n)
                        break
        if 'FEMALE' in k:
            for key in db[k]:
                if year == key:
                    for n in db[k][year]:
                        list_2.append(n)
                        break
    list.sort()
    new_list = [()]
    list_2.sort()
    new_list_2 = [()]

    for k in db:
        if 'MALE' in k:
            for i in range(len(list)):
                new_list.append((list[i],i+1))
            for key in db[k]:
                if year == key:
                    for n in db[k][year]:
                        for i in range(len(new_list)):
                            for j in range(len(new_list[i])):
                                if new_list[i][j] == n:
                                    db[k][year] = new_list[i]
        if 'FEMALE' in k:
            for i in range(len(list_2)):
                new_list_2.append((list_2[i],i+1))
            for key in db[k]:
                if year == key:
                    for n in db[k][year]:
                        for i in range(len(new_list_2)):
                            for j in range(len(new_list_2[i])):
                                if new_list_2[i][j] == n:
                                    db[k][year] = new_list_2[i]
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: ok sorry. first time asking question. I have to find out how to update

Comment: Did I update it correctly?

Comment: I added some newlines to your "database" in hopes that it would be more clear what data you're starting with -- However, it looks to me like you haven't got all your parenthesis/braces in the right places.

Comment: I'm not not understanding what you changed with the database. The first dictionary key is a tuple of strings and the value is another dictionary with a year as the key and a tuple of integers as the value.

Comment: correct syntax is: database = {('Spot','DOG'):{2013:(612,1), 2014:(598,3)},('Princess','CAT'):{2013:(713,2)},('Smokey', 'CAT'):{2013:(523,1), 2014:(514,1)},('Fido', 'DOG'):{2013:(558, 2), 2014:(655, 1)},('Sparky','DOG'):{2104:(572,2)}}

Comment: but I don't understand what is the task, each name occures in database only once, what is the meaningo of tules e.g. (612, 1) ?

Comment: The 612 is the number of cats or dogs with that name for the given year. The 1 is the rank. I have to rank the most popular dog names and cat names (separately) for a particular year.

Comment: So 612 dogs were names spot in the year 2013 and only 558 dogs were names Fido for the year 2013 so Spot would have rank 1 and Spot would have rank 2.

Comment: If there is a tie in counts, assign all names with the same rank and make sure the next rank is adjusted
accordingly. Given counts of A:10, B:5, C:5, D:5, E:1, they'd get rankings of A=1, B=2, C=2, D=2, E=5

Comment: Egregiously unclear. What's your specific problem? How to sort a tuple? Then formulate the question as such (and don't be surprised when it's instantly closed as a duplicate).

Comment: Why do have `MALE` and `FEMALE` in your code? Shouldn't these be `CAT` and `DOG`?

Comment: I'm sorry it isn't very clear. For each animal I need to rank them based on most popular name for the year. The database is a dictionary with a tuple as the key and a nested dictionary as the value. The tuple key is ('name', 'animal') The nested dictionary has a year for the key a tuple for a value. The tuple value is (number_of_names, rank). So I take all the cats for the year 2013 sort based on number_of_names and then change the rank value to reflect that sorting.

Comment: Yes it should be CAT or DOG. my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

```
database = {('TEST','DOG'):{2013:(612,1), 2014:(598,3)}, ('Spot','DOG'):{2013:(612,1), 2014:(598,3)},('Princess','CAT'):{2013:(713,2)},
            ('Princess1','CAT'):{2013:(713,2)},('Smokey', 'CAT'):{2013:(523,1), 2014:(514,1)},('Smokey1', 'CAT'):{2013:(523,1), 2014:(514,1)},('Fido', 'DOG'):{2013:(558, 2), 2014:(655, 1)},('Sparky','DOG'):{2104:(572,2)}}

def rank_names_for_one_year(db, year):
    temp = {'DOG' : [], 'CAT' : []}
    for k, v in db.items():
        if year not in v:
            continue
        temp[k[1]].append((v[year][0], k[0]))

    for animal_type, v in temp.items():
        rank = 0
        countPrev = -1
        for i, (count, name) in enumerate(reversed(sorted(v))):
            if countPrev != count:
                rank = i + 1
            countPrev = count
            db[(name, animal_type)][year] = (count, rank)


rank_names_for_one_year(database, 2013)
```

Comment: I get an attribute error. dictionary has no attribute iteritems. not sure what that means, but I think I can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you intend to teach something, more explanation is probably in order. Though, since it's so unclear what the OP doesn't understand, it's as unclear what specifically to explain...

Comment: @Adele if you use Python 3 items() instead of iteritems() should work

Comment: Yes that worked. Thank you so much!!! I understand how most of the code works but I'm not sure where the seq and animal_type comes from. I know they are the parameters but how does python know what value to use?

Comment: the update function is defined inside rank_names_for_one_year and it is executed in the two last lines of rank_names_for_one_year, seq and animal_type are passed there, I made this in order not to write the same code two times

Comment: Oh this makes so much sense now! I can't thank you enough. Sorry I was so confusing. You're brilliant. Thank you.

Comment: I made it a little bit shorter

Comment: if it possible to rank them where if there is a tie then the rank is adjusted accordingly? So if 'a' ranked 1 and b ranked 1 then c would rank 3 not 2.

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you. Can you explain the for i,(count,name) enumerate line?

Comment: try list(enumerate(['a','b','c'])) in your python console, in v there are pairs (count, name), so enumerate "returnes" (0, (count0, name0)), (1, (count1, name1)),...

Comment: Oh I get it. I was trying enumerate earlier but didn't know how to get rid of the counting number and just have the tuple. I think I understand now. Thank you again.